# Why is List<Float>.toFloatArray so slow compared to filling a FloatArray? (bug?)

Tags: android, arrays, list, opengl-es, kotlin

In my Android phone application there are many large Lists of Floats (100000+). In order to use them with OpenGl, the Lists are converted to FloatArrays and then to bytebuffers. I ran into performance problems and after many hours, it seems that the Kotlin .toFloatArray() function is very slow.

Some test results on my Samsung Galaxy Phone:

```
                        elapsed time(msec)  time/float(microsec)        
                            max min  avg 
fillFloatArray               70  39  59,7      6.0
fillFloatList               472 357 444,1     44.4
convertListToArrayLooping   165 101 155,2     15.5
convertWithToFloatArray     388 318 367,3     36.7

Number of floats    10000               
runs                   10
(the average time / float is the same for a list of 100000 floats)
```

Filling a floatarray with values is fast and filling a List with floats is 7.4 times slower.

However converting the List to a floatarray by the **standard function List.toFoatArray()** is 6.1 times slower than simply filling the array, it is also **2.4 times slower** than looping over the List. It is almost as slow as filling an empty List with Floats!

I expected a conversion time closer to the time of simply filling the array?

Does the performance of .toFloatArray() make sense? And what is the fastest or at least a faster way to convert a List to a Bytebuffer?

Below the small test program, for reference.

```
class PlayGround {
private val stopwatch = Timing()

private val arraylist: MutableList<Float> = arrayListOf()
private val fillFloatArray = Results()
private val fillFloatList = Results()
private val convertListToArrayLooping = Results()
private val convertWithToFloatArray = Results()

fun checkSpeed () {
    for (i in 0 until 10) {     // do the timing ten times to get an average
        // filling a floatarray with 10000 floats
        stopwatch.start()
        var array = FloatArray(10000, { it * 1f })
        fillFloatArray.add(stopwatch.stop())

        // filling a list with 10000 floats
        stopwatch.start()
        for (i in 0 until 10000) {
            arraylist.add(i * 1f)
        }
        fillFloatList.add(stopwatch.stop())

        // converting the fulllist to a floatarray by looping
        stopwatch.start()
        for (i in 0 until arraylist.size) {
            array[i] = arraylist[i]
        }
        convertListToArrayLooping.add(stopwatch.stop())

        // converting the fullist to a floatarray with toFloatArray
        stopwatch.start()
        array = arraylist.toFloatArray()
        convertWithToFloatArray.add(stopwatch.stop())
        arraylist.clear()
    }
}

private class Results {
    private var max = Long.MIN_VALUE
    private var min = Long.MAX_VALUE
    private var sum = 0L
    private var avg = 0L
    var measurePoints: MutableList<Long> = arrayListOf()

    fun add (msrp: Long) {
        measurePoints.add(msrp)
        if (msrp > max) max = msrp
        if (msrp < min) min = msrp
        sum += msrp
        avg = sum / measurePoints.size
    }

    fun clear() {
        measurePoints.clear()
        max = Long.MIN_VALUE
        min = Long.MAX_VALUE
        sum = 0L
        avg = 0L
    }

    fun max(): Long { return max}
    fun min(): Long { return min}
    fun sum(): Long { return sum}
    fun avg(): Long { return avg}

}
}
```

Comment: Note that `toFloatArray` also has to allocate a new array, so it's not necessarily a fair comparison.

Comment: You've not specifying the initial size of `arraylist`. Use `arraylist 
 = ArrayList<Float>(10000)`.

Comment: The standard function is  `Collection.toFloatArray`, but you're using indexed iteration to transfer the data from the list to the array. Indexed iteration is not available to the stdlib fun.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That is a far point, however that would cost 60 msec for 10000 floats still making toFloatArray way slower than looping over the List?

Comment: @miensol, I rerun it with the allocation upfront, it does not change the results (alos to my surprice)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thats exactly the point, I would normally not use the indexed iteration but this is faster than the Collection.toFlaotArray which seems very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code, it tries to put the two ways of conversion on a more equal footing than your tests:

```
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

const val PROBLEM_SIZE = 1_000_000

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val array = FloatArray(PROBLEM_SIZE, { it * 1f })
    val list: List<Float> = array.map { it }

    println("warmup")
    (1..20).forEach {
            list.myToFloatArray()
            list.toFloatArray()
    }

    println("list.toFloatArray " + (1..10).map {
        gc()
        measureTimeMillis {
            list.myToFloatArray()
        }
    }.average())

    println("collection.toFloatArray " + (1..10).map {
        gc()
        measureTimeMillis {
            list.toFloatArray()
        }
    }.average())
}

fun List<Float>.myToFloatArray(): FloatArray {
    val result = FloatArray(size)
    for (index in 0 until size)
        result[index] = this[index]
    return result
}

fun gc() {
    System.gc()
    System.gc()
}
```

This is a typical result

```
list.toFloatArray 3.4
collection.toFloatArray 5.2
```

First, the difference is less pronounced than in your tests, and second,  the standard function is `Collection.toFloatArray` and cannot use indexed iteration.

Comment: Excellent piece of code, (I still need to learn Kotlin I think :-). Also in your case the indexed approach is 1.5 times faster. If Collection.toFloatArray is this slow, I have to redesign my application, avoiding Lists and work with bare floatarrays only.

Comment: I'd recommend that in any case, memory overhead of list is very large.